# Is it still haram if we make eyes and face on keychains because we need money?

Tags: halal-haram

I have a small busness online, I sell handmade keychains, in that I sell animals and some cartoons, and they literally have eyes and mouth and nose, like every detail. But I read that it is haram to make them, so I stopped making them, because I don't want to earn gunnah.

Recently I have however been really in need of money, I work but it is not helping, so I had to restart my shop.

I want to ask if it is allowed for me to make eyes and mouth just because I am in need of money.

Answer (score 1):

Animated beings and cartoons are haram in Islam. If you sell them and earn money it won’t be halal. If the money is not halal then your food won’t be halal. So halal earning is important . Making picture is a major sin in Islam.

```
the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said, according to the saheeh hadeeth: “Every image maker will be in the Fire.” And he (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The most severely punished of people on the Day of Resurrection will be the image-makers, those who tried to imitate the creation of Allaah.” And he (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “The makers of these images will be punished on the Day of Resurrection, and they will be told, ‘Give life to that which you have created.’”
```

It is not allowed to create pictures of humans or animals which have souls. But you can surely make creatures that don’t have soul like trees mountains etc. I know there’s struggles in life but if you need money you earn from halal sources.

Thanks

Comment: "Give life to that which you have created" means don't claim to be the Creator of matter nor guide to the Right Path.

Answer (score -1):

It's haram to make idols of images. Because of the emphasis on this in Islam it's generally been taken that to involve oneself in the making of images itself is haram. This is not the case. The *intention* to make an idol of an image is what is important here and not merely the image itself. If this is missing, then there is, generally speaking, no objection to pursuing a career or a talent for image making or otherwise being involved in such.

The Dar al-Iftya Al-Missriyya, the main religious institution of Egypt has issued fatwas specifically on this. They say:

> Drawing humans is permissible according to some scholars. Maliki scholars ... and the Hanbali scholar, Ibn Hamdan have maintained this position ... In his *Mussanaf* [Hadith collection ordered by topic], Ibn Abu Shaybah reported this opinion from the venerated *tabi'i* [a person born after the Prophets death (pbuh) and who accompanied some of his Companions] Al-Qasim Ibn Mohammed, and who was known as one of the best scholars of his time. The Hadith reads:

> Ibn 'Awn said: I entered upon al-Qasim in his house which was located in the upper part of Mecca and saw a *hajla* [a net placed above the bed to serve as protection against flying insects] with the images of a beaver and a phoenix.

They then conclude:

> Therefore, there is no objection to drawing animates such as humans, animals and the like; whether from imagination, nature or photographs. There is no objection in Islamic law in pursuing this talent provided that the drawings are void of anything prohibited and do no incite sexual desire.

Answer (score -3):

> In the absence of Moses, his people made from their **˹golden˺ jewellery an idol of a calf that *made a lowing sound***. Did they not see that it could neither speak to them nor ˹even˺ guide them to the ˹Right˺ Path? Still they took it as a god and were wrongdoers. (Quran.com, 7:148)

> ˹Remember˺ when he questioned his father and his people, “What are these statues to which you are so devoted?” They replied, “We found our forefathers worshipping them.” He responded, “Indeed, you and your forefathers have been clearly astray.” (op. cit., 21:52-54)

> Give just measure, and cause no loss (to others by fraud). And weigh with scales true and upright. And **withhold not things justly due to men**, nor do evil in the land, working mischief. (alquranclasses.com, 26:181-183)

> This is certainly a revelation from the Lord of all worlds, which the trustworthy spirit ˹Gabriel˺ brought down into your heart ˹O Prophet˺—so that you may be one of the warners— in a clear Arabic tongue. And it has indeed been ˹foretold˺ in the Scriptures of those before. (op. cit., 26:192–6)

> O believers! Do not enter any house other than your own until you have asked for permission and greeted its occupants. This is best for you, so perhaps you will be mindful. (op. cit., 24:27)

> Give full measure, and cause no loss ˹to others˺. Weigh with an even balance, and **do not defraud people** of their property. Nor go about spreading corruption in the land. And fear the One Who created you and ˹all˺ earlier peoples. (op cit., 26:181–4)